# Exterior Algebra Graded Ring Structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra, graded-rings

In Hatcher's Example 3.13 he defines the Exterior Algebra $\Lambda_R[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]$ over a commutative ring $R$ with identity to be the free $R$-module with basis the finite products $\alpha_{i_1}\cdots\alpha_{i_k}$ with $i_1 < \cdots <i_k$ with associative, distributive multiplication defined by the rules $\alpha_i \alpha_j = -\alpha_j \alpha_i$ and $\alpha_i^2=0$, and the empty product serving as the multiplicative identity.

He then simply says that the exterior algebra becomes a commutative graded ring by specifying odd dimensions for the generators $\alpha_i$.

> I understand the $\alpha_i$ need to have odd dimensions in order to satisfy the $\alpha_i \alpha_j = -\alpha_j \alpha_i$, but how exactly does the exterior algebra decompose as a direct sum, which is part of the definition of a graded algebra?

Comment: What do you mean "specifying odd dimensions"?  Aren't the products $\prod_{j=1}^n \alpha_{i_j}$ defined to have grade $n$? Then the space decomposes into direct sums of the pieces generated by elements of separate grades?

Comment: @rschwieb I'm not 100% sure what he means by that -- that's just what he said. I've never studied exterior algebras before so I would have preferred a bit more detail from him.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us write $E=\Lambda_R[\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n]$.  A basis for $E$ as an $R$-module is the set of all monomials $\alpha_{i_1}\dots\alpha_{i_m}$ where $i_1<\dots<i_m$.  Now for each $i$, let $d_i$ be an odd integer that will be the degree of $\alpha_i$.  We can then define the degree of a monomial $\alpha_{i_1}\dots\alpha_{i_m}$ to be $d_{i_1}+\dots+d_{i_m}$.  Let $E_d$ be the span of all monomials of degree $d$.  Then $E$ is the direct sum of the submodules $E_d$, making $E$ a graded module.  Furthermore, this grading is compatible with the ring structure making $E$ a graded algebra, and it is in fact a commutative graded algebra since each $d_i$ is odd (though this takes a little work to check).

Comment: When you write the basis for $E$ as $\alpha_{i_1}\cdots \alpha_{i_m}$, should that be $\alpha_{i_1} \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_{i_m}$?

Comment: If you are writing the multiplication operation as $\wedge$, then that would be correct.

Comment: Is it not always with a $\wedge$? I'm not sure since this is new to me.

Comment: It is often commonly written as just juxtaposition or $\cdot$, particularly when you have a naturally arising algebra which happens to be isomorphic to an exterior algebra (rather than starting with a vector space and then taking its exterior algebra).

Comment: Can you explain the meaning of dimension of $a_i$ ? @EricWofsey

Comment: @DevendraSinghRana: $E$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$-graded ring, and $\alpha_i$ is in the $d_i$th graded piece.